# Auto start in android

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I use

```
Intent.putExtra("autostart", true)
```

to automatically start a camera without asking the user to click on the start button?

Comment: Please be more specific, describing in more detail what you want to accomplish and what you've tried.

Comment: @ebohlman I have written code to launch camera using intent and I want that after the camera is launched, the user need not click the start button of the camera, it should start recording of its own. For this I tried using putExtra("autostart", true) but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

i thick the BroadcastReceiver can solve your question，you can start a camera in onReceive callback function

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please expand your answer (e.g. with a sample code). Answers should generally be self-contained i.e. require no further resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by calling intent with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`  and rest you can check this link [Camera start](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Comment: This will launch camera but would not start recording of its own

Comment: Android does not provide auto start for recording, if you want to implement thi,which will require you to code camera app in you application... then this link would be useful for you http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/